# Spark Error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source$class`

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

> **UPDATE:** Issue Fixed. Was a versioning issue. Needed to change spark-core and others to version 2.2.0.

I am new to Apache Spark. I am trying to send logs through Kafka and process them using Spark Streaming before passing it to ElasticSearch. However I am getting the following error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/Source$class
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSource.(KafkaSource.scala:87)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider.createSource(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:152)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.createSource(DataSource.scala:240)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(StreamingQueryManager.scala:245)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(StreamingQueryManager.scala:241)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:279)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$3.apply(TreeNode.scala:279)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:278)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:268)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:241)
>     at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:287)
>     at com.fork.SreamingApp.App.main(App.java:78)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.Source$class
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
>     at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>     ... 13 more

Here are my Code files

**App.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NotSerializableException, InterruptedException {
        App streamingApp = new App();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                  .builder()
                  .appName("Java Spark SQL data sources example")
                  .master("local")
                  .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> ds1 = spark
                  .readStream()
                  .format("kafka")
                  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:32770")
                  .option("subscribe", "context3")
                  .load();

        StreamingQuery query = ds1.writeStream()
                  .format("console")
                  .start();

        query.awaitTermination();
        System.out.println("DONE");



}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.fork</groupId>
 <artifactId>SreamingApp</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>SreamingApp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
     <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
     <version>2.12.0</version>
   </dependency>


   <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>3.8.1</version>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.0</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
     <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
     <version>2.2.3</version>
   </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>bson</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId> 
        <version>1.6.3</version> </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

How do I fix this? Please help me out.

Comment: This is most often a case of version mismatch. Please make sure that the spark versions are same. `<artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId><version>2.0.0</version>` `<artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>       <version>2.0.2</version>`

Comment: You put `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11` twice in your POM... Remove one and also try removing explict import of `kafka-clients`... Plus, you need to add `<scope>provided</scope>` to Spark Core, SQL, and Streaming

Comment: @cricket_007 I tried that, its still not working

Comment: @arnavchakravarthy Please edit your question and add 1) the command to package/build/assembly your Spark app, 2) the entire `spark-submit` command. Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The issue was finally fixed, it was a versioning issue. Had to make spark core and the others version 2.2.0, and it started working like a charm :)

Comment: @JacekLaskowski The issue was finally fixed, it was a versioning issue. Had to make spark core and the others version 2.2.0, and it started working like a charm :)